# Parse C preprocessor statement, ending with a comment, in Antlr4

Tags: antlr4

I am trying to create a grammar rule for the following line:

```
#define FLAG /* this is a comment */
```

and

```
#define FLAG // this is another
```

This is my current rule:

```
DefineDirective
    :   '#' Whitespace? 'define' ~[\r\n]* Newline
        -> channel(2)
    ;
```

However, it will also consume the comments. I need todo some check if the line contains '//' or '/*', and in that case break, but I cant figure out how. Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a working solution, so sharing it:

```
DefineDirective
    :   '#' Whitespace? 'define' ((~[/\r\n]) | ('/' ~('*'|'/')))*
        -> channel(2)
    ;
```

(~[/\r\n]) = match anything except newline and /

('/' ~('*'|'/')) = match /, but only if its not followed by *, or another /